# Add dashed line with ggplot2

Tags: r, dataframe, rbind

I have trouble making the WBank line dashed and that it also appears dashed in the legend. This is what I have written so far:

```
ggplot(data = Differences_TODO, aes(x = Years,y= MeanDifference))+geom_line(aes(color=region)) +
  labs(x = "Figure 2 (Modified) - Extra hours to get to work in Israel by region of residence" , y = "Extra Hours")+
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),legend.position = c(0.2,0.8))+
  scale_x_continuous(n.breaks = 10) + 
  scale_linetype_manual(values=c("solid","dotted")) +
  theme(legend.title=element_blank()) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "black"))
```

I don't understand why scale_linetype_manual is not working properly.
This is how my graph currently looks like:
[image: Graph]

Comment: You need to specify that you want to use linetype as an aesthetic. Try `geom_line(aes(linetype=region))`

Comment: Thanks ! It worked perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Phil for helping out, the correct code should include `geom_line(aes(linetype=region))`

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.